# Find the Area of Triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Another question on my daily test, I suspect that is there is a theory that I haven't learn or the question doesn't have an answer. Try solving it :)

[image: Question]

> Triangle ABC is divided into 6 small triangles. The area of the small triangles are listed. What is the area of triangle ABC?
>
> **A.)** 53
>
> **B.)** 56
>
> **C.)** 63
>
> **D.)** 68
>
> **E.)** 73

Comment: What is $16,8$??

Comment: In where I lived, symbols like {.} and {,} are switched by their definition. 16,8 = 168 / 10

Comment: See [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva's_theorem) and the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Making use of the fact that bases of the triangles are same, we can solve any two of the following ratios to find $x$ and $y$ :
$$\frac{8}{6}=\frac{16.8+x+8}{y+7+6}$$
$$\frac{7}{y}=\frac{8+6+7}{x+16.8+y}$$
$$\frac{16.8}{x}=\frac{7+y+16.8}{x+8+6}$$

***Note:*** If the third equation doesn't satisfy the values derived from any two equations, then such a triangle does not exists.